# UE4 - Easy way to focus and frame camera on selected object with blueprint? Like the F shortcut in the editor

Tags: camera, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I want to develop a functionality where a user will be able to press a button that move the focus of the camera to a selected object and reposition the camera (with a fixed FoV) to frame the object correctly.

In face, I want to reproduce the behavior of the F shortcut in the editor:

- In the editor, you can select an object
- You can press F key
- The camera move, put the select object in the center of the view and
  adjust the distance (arm length) to make the whole object visible.

Is there an easy way to reproduce that in blueprint? I'm actually doing trigonometry stuff and using bounding box size but I'm pretty sure there is a better way. I don't want to recreate a feature that may be already accessible (and already developed in the editor).

Image: The behavior in editor that I want to reproduce in-game
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Bounding boxes can be useful, but in this case you'll want to know the center of the bounding box if your Actor doesn't have a proper pivot (which can be solved by using a Scene Component as a root in the Actor's hierarchy) so you can have a good anchor to focus at.

Then, you need both an angle and a distance to set the camera's new location. Take your newfound pivot as a center (either by calculating the center of the bounding box or by using `GetActorLocation`), then you'll set the camera's transform at a certain point in space calculating the location by using Sine and Cosine of the provided angle.

If you use `SetActorLocation` or the World Transform directly, the camera will jump. To soften this, check the camera's current location, calculate the new one and spawn a spline using those two points in space. This way you can move the camera smoothly by using a speed variable, `GetWorldDeltaSeconds` and `GetLocationAndRotationAlongSpline`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a very easy way.

Thing is...

...to focus/frame an object you have selected in the outliner,
is pretty easy in the viewport of the editor,
by just  and then pressing 'F'.
Just as you stated.
On the other hand, in the "BlueprintEditor", for some unknown reason
(hard to believe I know, but try it.. ^^  ...),
 you will just have to select (f.i. the camera) in the "Components"-pane,
(just like you would in the Editor windows "Outliner")
but after you have selected it there, 
you will
NEED TO CLICK on an empty space somewhere
IN THE VIEWPORT. ¯\__(ツ)_/¯ 
After you have clicked somewhere in the Blueprint-Editors viewport, you just press 'F' 
and presto : 
Your camera is in the frame of your viewport.
(Neat little time eating bug-no-bug thing, I know.)

Answer (score 0):

You can either open up the console command, ensuring your are executing a command (Cmd) instead of python, and use the command `CAMERA ALIGN`.

Alternatively if you're using blueprint, you can use the `Execute Console Command` node and fill it in with `CAMERA ALIGN` to get the intended result.

Note that this is equivalent to pressing `F` in the viewport. If you want to contextually select things, you can use blueprint's `Set Selected Level Actors` node which takes in an array of actors from which you can use to select specific actors before calling `CAMERA ALIGN`.